# how to get keys in one column and values in other in a dataframe , my dataframe looks like:

Tags: python, dataframe

```
ids      values
123     {'name':john, 'lastname':cal}
159     {'Age':21, 'add':45698}
```

I want to convert it into:

```
|ids|  name| lastname| age| add|
|123|  john|  cal|     na|  na |
|159|  na|     na|     21| 45698|
```

please help me how to do this

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
```

You can use `DataFrame()` method and `tolist()` method:

```
result=pd.DataFrame(df['values'].tolist())
```

Now if you print `result` you will get your desired output:

```
    name    lastname    Age     add
0   john    cal         NaN     NaN
1   NaN     NaN         21.0    45698.0
```